# C Program to find prime number

Tags: c

Hey guys so I need to make a program which asks the user to enter a number as a argument and then let them know if it is a prime number or 0 otherwise. So the code I have so far is as follows but I am a little confused on how to make it run through all the possible values of the and make sure that it isn't a non-prime number. Right now what happens is that the program opens, I enter a value and nothing happens. Note: I have math in the header as I am unsure if it is needed or not at this stage.

EDIT: SO I MADE THE CHANGES SUGGESTED AND ALSO ADDED A FOR LOOP HOWEVER WHEN I GO TO COMPILE MY PROGRAM I GET AN WARNING SOMETHING ALONG THE LINES OF '***CONTROL MAY REACH END OF NON-VOID FUNCTION***'. HOWEVER THE PROGRAM DOES COMPILE WHEN I GO TO ENTER A NUMBER AND HIT ENTER IRRELEVANT OT WHETHER OR NOT IT IS A PRIME NUMBER I GET AN ERROR BACK SAYING '***FLOATING POINT EXCEPTION: 8***'.

EDIT 2: THE FLOATING POINT ERROR HAS BEEN FIXED HOWEVER NOW THE PROGRAM SEEMS TO THINK THAT EVERY NUMBER IS NON - PRIME AND OUTPUTS IT THIS WAY. I CAN'T SEEM TO SEE WHY IT WOULD DO THIS. I AM ALSO STILL GETTING THE '***CONTROL MAY REACH END OF NON-VOID FUNCTION***' WARNING

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int prime(int a){
    int b;

    for(b=1; b<=a; b++){
        if (a%b==0)
        return(0);
    }
    if(b==a){
        return(1);
    }
}
int main(void){

    int c, answer;

    printf("Please enter the number you would like to find is prime or not= ");
    scanf("%d",&c);

    answer = prime(c);

    if(answer==1){
        printf("%d is a prime number \n",c);
    }
    else
        printf("%d is not a prime number\n",c);
    }
```

Comment: Let's start with the basics here. Do you actually know what a prime number is? If so, can you explain how your program is supposed to be able to distinguish between prime and non-prime numbers?

Comment: I see what you meant so I went and had a look. I have made some changes please refer to OP.

Comment: `a%b` : when  b==0, Cause FLOATING POINT EXCEPTION

Comment: Oh I see the problem I had "  for(b=0; b<=a; b++)" instead of  
"for(b=1; b<=a; b++)" however now the problem is that every number entered is coming out as a non prime

Comment: The remainder  by divide 1 is 0.

Comment: These ... capitals ... hurt ... my ... eyes ... %-(

Comment: Why are you screaming at us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modified your function a little. Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int prime(int a)
{
    int b=2,n=0;

    for(b=2; b<a; b++)
    {
        if (a%b==0)
        {
            n++;
            break;
        }
    }

    return(n);
}
int main(void)
{

    int c, answer;

    printf("Please enter the number you would like to find is prime or not= ");
    scanf("%d",&c);

    answer = prime(c);

    if(answer==1)
    {
        printf("%d is not a prime number \n",c);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is a prime number\n",c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Explanation-

1. In the for loop, I am starting from 2 because, I want to see if the given number is divisible by 2 or the number higher than 2. And I have used break, because once the number is divisible, I don't want to check anymore. So, it will exit the loop.
2. In your main function, you had not assigned properly for the printf() statement. If answer==1, it is not a prime number. (Because this implies that a number is divisible by some other number). You had written, it is a prime number(which was wrong).

If you have any doubts, let me hear them.

Comment: Just  one question. Where you used break can I also use return(0) to stop the program there or must it be a break there? Oh and I see the mistake I made in the main function. Thank you very much for you help it is appreciated.

Comment: @zwarrior You can change your return value to bool in this function, because there can be only two conditions. Either it is a prime or not. Besides this algorithm can be enhanced a lot.

Comment: @SamLiyanage Yeah, sure. But, you have to modify the code little bit. If you use return(0), the value 'n' will not be returned to the main program because once compiler sees return(0), it won't go any further in that function. So, '0' will be returned. So, modify these parts if you want to use return(0), 1) you can remove the variable 'n' from the function 'prime', 2) Instead of the condition- if(answer==1), you should use if(answer==0)

Comment: @Valinho, Ya. You are right. But, if the code is modified like I have mentioned in the above comment, we don't need the variable 'n'.

Comment: @zwarrior Oh okay I shall make those changes thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You never initialized `i` (it has indeterminate value - local variable).

**2.** You never call function `is_prime`.

And using a loop will be good idea .Comparing to what you have right now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start with trial division.  What is the minimal set of numbers you need to divide by to decide whether `a` is prime?  When can you prove that, if `a` has a factor `q`, it must have a smaller factor `p`?  (Hint: it has a prime decomposition.)

Comment: I am only just starting on having more than one function so something like having prime decomposition seems very out there for me especially after seeing the wiki example.

Comment: Okay.  What I meant is this: if *n* is a composite, it must have a prime factor less than or equal to √ *n*. (If it has a factor *m* greater than the square root, then *n* / *m* is a smaller factor, and if it has a composite factor, that in turn has a smaller prime factor.)  However, for this assignment, you can ignore optimality and trial-divide by more numbers than you could get away with.  It will still work.

Comment: Yeah I think once I start gettting more into the semester I will be asked by the lecturers to use things like that opposed to trial like I did. But thank you

Answer (score 0):

Some errors your program had in your prime finding algorithm:

- You start the loop with number 1 - this will make *all* numbers you test to be **not prime**, because when you test if the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) of a division by `1` is zero, it's true (all numbers are divisible by 1).
- You go through the loop until `a`, which modulo will also be zero (all number are divisible by **themselves**).
- The condition for a number to be prime is that it must be divisible by `1` and `itself`. That's it. So you **must not test that** in that loop.

On **`main`**, the error you're getting (**control reaches end of non-void function**) is because you declare `main` to return an `int`.

```
int main(void)
```

And to solve that, you should put a `return 0;` statement on the end of your `main` function. Bellow, a working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int prime(int a)
{
    int b;

    for (b = 2; b < a; b++) {
        if (a % b == 0)
            return (0);
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{

    int c, answer;

    printf
        ("Please enter the number you would like to find is prime or not= ");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    answer = prime(c);

    if (answer == 1) {
        printf("%d is a prime number \n", c);
    } else {
        printf("%d is not a prime number\n", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

On a side note, don't use the **CAPSLOCK** to write full sentences. **[Seems like you're yelling.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kbJv.jpg)**

Comment: Oh I see the mistake, now I feel very dumb. I understood the modulus part but I must have neglected the divisor.  Oh and I also see why the return 0 was needed at the end, just to make sure that i have it correct is it there to stop the main function from going back and attempting to repeat?

Comment: And thank you for your help. And sorry for using caps lock. I just thought it would be easier to nice the edit my mistake.

Comment: @SamLiyanage No, the `return 0;` is a convention. The `main` function return 0 when it executed and served it's purpose **without errors**.

Comment: Oh okay so its not just a one off. Thank you for the info

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically the maximum divisor of a number can be as a large as the square of it, so we just need to loop until sqrt(number).

A valid function would be:

```
//Function that returns 1 if number is prime and 0 if it's not
int prime(number) {
    int i;

    for (i = 2; i < sqrt(number); i++) {
        if (a % i == 0)
            return (0);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Try `i < sqrt(number)` for the test condition. Also, consider that `sqrt` is a rather slow function to use in this context, particularly if `number` is large. Finally... you didn't address OP's problems (in bold-italic)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n , a, c = 0;
    printf ("enter the value of number you want to check");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    //Stopping user to enter 1 as an input.
    if(n==1)
    {
        printf("%d cannot be entered as an input",n);
    }
    for(a = 2;a < n; a++)
    {
        if(n%a==0)
        {
            c=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(c==0 && n!=1)
    {
        printf("%d is a prime number \n",n);
    }
    else
    {
        if(c!=0 && n!=1)
        {
        printf("%d is not a prime number \n",n);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

  int x,i;

  printf("enter the number : ");
  scanf("%d",&x);
  for ( i=2; i<x;i++){

        if ( x % i == 0){
            printf("%d",x); 
            printf(" is not prime number ");    
            printf("it can be divided by : ");
            printf("%d",i);
            break;
        }[this is best solution ][1]

  }
    if( i>=x) {
        printf("%d",x);
        printf(" is prime number");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the best solution, but on first glance it looks like it works