# c program to find sum of first 1000 prime number

Tags: c

I want to print sum of the first 1000 prime numbers. I don't know if the following implementation is right and where it is wrong. Moreover, how can I optimize this implementation, which is required for extra off course?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int prime(int no,int lim)
{
    int i=2,flag=0;
    for(;i<=lim;i++)
    {
        if(no%i==0)
        {   
            flag=1;     
        }
    }
    return flag ;
}

int main()
{
    int i=4,count=2,j,k,l,n=4;
    double sum=5.0;

    for(;count<=1000;)
    {   
        j=sqrt(i);
        k=prime(i,j);
        if(k==0)
        {
            //printf("\n%d",i);
            sum+=(double)i;
            //for(l=0;l<100000;l++);//just to reduce speed of the program

            count++;
        }
    i++;

}
printf("\n%f",sum);
        return 0;   
}
```

Comment: If you do a Google search you will find multiple examples of C programs that do prime numbers. For instance see this discussion https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-simplest-program-to-find-prime-numbers-in-C++

Comment: You've got several flaws here: count and i are not equal; prime() will return wrong values if your number is even, I think. What is your output?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649594/c-program-to-find-prime-numbe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C program to find a prime number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549380/c-program-to-find-a-prime-number)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know if the following implementation is right and where it is wrong.

The implementation is correct except for an off-by-one error: Since `count` is the number of primes that were already taken into account, the loop condition `count<=1000` causes the loop to be run one more time when 1000 primes have already been summed, adding the 1001. prime. Correct is: `count<1000`.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize your code you better use **Sieve of Eratosthenes** to generate prime up to your limit, then add these primes. To know how **sieve** works, read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/) article.